# Laravel app throwing Exception after running vagrant reload

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

So I decided to do upgrades on my framework and the working environment. I upgraded my laravel version from 5.7 to 5.8. Upgraded my vagrant, virtual box and homestead to the latest versions. Since this update, i've been getting this error:
[image]

Now whenever I destroy the vagrant box and create another one, everything works fine. But the minute I do a vagrant reload again, this exception is thrown. I've searched through google and StackOverflow for days now but I don't get anything relating to what's causing my error. Any help will be truly appreciated.

Also anytime I try to run the php:artisan command, i'm getting the following error:

In LoadConfiguration.php line 68:

Unable to load the "app" configuration file.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling vendor folder completely?

Comment: @Naranz yes I have. I think the issue is with vagrant/homestead because even a fresh laravel install throws the same error. And as I said, if i destroy the vagrant box currently used and bring it back up again, it works. But I don't want to have to be doing this cause I have to restore the database backup again and it's not an elegant way to work